# How can i write simple calculator in the easiest way possible in python Tkinter GUI? I tried but it's not working

Tags: python, tkinter

## here is the code

```
import Tkinter
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import *

calc_window=Tk()
calc_window.title("Calculator")

# the function is the problem
text=StringVar()

def click(nums):
    text.set(nums)

frame=Frame(calc_window)

frame.grid()

entry=Entry(frame, textvariable="text")
entry.grid(column=0,row=0)

#creating buttons

nums="C+-/789*4561230="

b=0
buttonList=[]
for r in range(2,6):
    for c in range(2,6):
        buttonList.append(Button(frame, text=nums[b],command=click))
        buttonList[b].grid(row=r, column=c)
        b+=1

calc_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please **syntax highlighting** your code. check [Code Blocks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes, but nothing too major.

- Only one import of `Tkinter` is necessary, importing it as `tk` is common practice.
- In the `click` function, you'll probably want to add the string value to what is currently in the `StringVar`.
- For the `Entry` the `StringVar` variable `text` is desired, not the string "text".
- The main problem, when storing variables in the loop, the command will need a `lambda` that stores the value currently in the variable during that iteration of the loop.

Example:

```
import Tkinter as tk # only one Tkinter import is needed.

calc_window=tk.Tk()
calc_window.title("Calculator")

# the function is the problem
text=tk.StringVar()

def click(nums):
    #text.set(nums)
    text.set(text.get() + nums) # Need to get what is currently in the variable, then add to it.

frame=tk.Frame(calc_window)

frame.grid()

entry=tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=text) # the variable text, not the string "text".
entry.grid(column=0,row=0)

#creating buttons

nums="C+-/789*4561230="

b=0
buttonList=[]
for r in range(2,6):
    for c in range(2,6):
        buttonList.append(tk.Button(frame,
                                    text=nums[b],
                                    # A lambda is needed here to store the current iteration value.
                                    command=lambda n = nums[b]: click(n)))
        buttonList[b].grid(row=r, column=c)
        b+=1

calc_window.mainloop()
```

[image: Example]

There is still a bunch of work to go, but this should get you back on track.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate. I am just starting to learn python. And I am glad to be in this community